# What Kind of Worlds Would Ascended Beings Live In?

Tags: dimensions

We see examples in fiction all the time about sentient beings that transcend physical form into beings of thought/energy, but what kind of realms would these beings create/live in after leaving the corporeal universe behind? Would it be remotely familiar to us?

Comment: They live forever in our hearts.

Comment: This is a poll for opinions, therefore I am voting to close this question as "opinion-based". It's fine to have questions with lots of valid answers - but if every reasonable answer is exactly equally valid the question is not suited for the StackExchange network. We can help you with problems you encounter while building your world, but we can't build your world for you.

Comment: By definition they would live in places higher than they were before.  Otherwise they would be "Descended Beings", or possibly "Moved Laterally Beings".

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what ascended means to you. Here are some examples to explore:

### Different World or Different Universe

You can also imagine a higher plane by logging out of an RPG or other game. The "universe" might be a service, or a box on a desk. Understanding the programming may be a skill you possess, or not. You may have family or friends that that care about you and think you spend too much time in the "universe". You might have a job. The rules of how things get done - by having friends (socialism) or having equipment and skill (capitalism) very likely still apply. This is the Valhalla of Marvel's *Thor* - home is just another place to rest, and maybe enjoy some nice perks.

### Universe Adjacent

Alternatively, ascension may be travel outside the event horizon of the Big Bang, or to the beginning (or end) of time. Or time/space travel to some idyllic (or especially strategic) point in all of creation. This has been used in Fredick Pohl's *Gateway* (inside or outside of black holes), Isaac Asimov's *Foundation* (one of the two locations in the whole universe that are insignificant (safe) according to psychohistory).

### Same Universe, Different Dimension(s)

Or, the ascended might go somewhere where the eleven dimensions predicted by string theory aren't compactified to the three of space and one of time we're used to. It may be the same universe, but the ascended live in more of it. The ascended may be able to travel and manipulated these additional dimensions the way you and I walk across the room. The final battle in Marvel's *Dr. Strange* features entering an alternate dimension and easily looping time in a curve, creating an intentional "Groundhog Day" effect, dying countless times, while he waits for the big bad boss to cool down and negotiate. Or, in *Day After Tomorrow*, the monster invading Earth is constantly resetting time until it achieves the outcomes it is looking for.

Although it gets very little screen time, Marvel's Dr. Strange paints an awesome picture of these different dimensions. The big boss's dimension is timeless. It is a great arching story that is only told once, ever. In it, the war for Earth only happens once. However, because this timeless dimension touches timeful Earth in many places, on Earth this one story will play out countless times throughout time. The perspective and some of the characters may change, but it will always be the same story reflected through the prism of time.

### Notional Space

Used very well in Games Workshop's *Warhammer* series, but also used other places. Imagine an ascended individual steps into the higher plane where a popular folk song is playing and steps back into the "real" world on a different planet, where the same melody is playing on a radio. Distances millions of miles apart in the real world may be mere steps from one another while one side of your bedroom (near the *Princess Bride* poster) are months of travel through several kingdoms to the other side of your bedroom (near the *Neverending Story* promotional poster). Roads between the worlds are where notions overlap (such as taking a brick road and the yellow brick road). Notional space is so big that it's hard to imagine ascended beings socializing much, but maybe it happens.